# Auto Complete Jquery Not Working on the Hosting but work well on localhost

Tags: javascript, php, json

my autocomplete code working great on my localhost, but when i tried to live the code on the server, it doesnt work anymore.

i tried to modify the source url, header but still cannot solve.

Auto Complete jquery :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                // Selector input yang akan menampilkan autocomplete.
                $( "#keyword" ).autocomplete({
                    serviceUrl: "widget/sourcesearch.php",   
                    dataType: "JSON",           
                    onSelect: function (suggestion) {


                    }


                });
            })
</script>
```

PHP Sourcesearch.php file :

```
<?php
// Set header type konten.
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

//this is my connect to php code
include '../__cnc/cnc.php';

// Deklarasi variable keyword buah.
$keyword = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_REQUEST["query"]);

// Query ke database.

$query = "SELECT * FROM ms_product WHERE code LIKE '%$keyword%' ORDER BY code ASC limit 8";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
$result = mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

// Cek apakah ada yang cocok atau tidak.
if (count($result) > 0) {
    foreach($result as $data) {
        $output['suggestions'][] = [
            //'value' => $data['kecamatan'],
            'value' => $data['code'],
            'kota'  => $data['title']


        ];
    }

    // Encode ke JSON.
    echo json_encode($output);

// Jika tidak ada yang cocok.
} else {
    $output['suggestions'][] = [
        'value' => '',
        'kota'  => ''

    ];

    // Encode ke JSON.
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

Need your advice, thank you

on the localhost it show suggestion as well, but on live server the suggestion wont work.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details as per the How to Create a [mcve] page. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Comment: @Machavity hello thank you for your respond. it doesnt show any error, but all auto complete suggestion form on my site doenst work at all. here the screenshot  : 
expected (work on localhost) : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TmAS3k7N7tNT3tP-juSYp02EO6okKE6X/view?usp=sharing

On Live server hosting : 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VyD3I6ysNt4w81Y5fmTJ5ezL3SqxjFZw/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Dharman hello, can you give me a line that can caused sql  injection? because im using mysql_real_escape_string to catch the inputted.  and do you have suggestion for my problem?

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string` might help, but it is not a solution to SQL injections. Instead it makes your code bloated and overly-complicated, replace this with prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue. I got the problem was some jquery files were not included in the host server. It worked fine when I uploaded the missing jquery file. Just check local jquery files against that of the server.